# The product of distances from $n$ points to a point on unit circle less than $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, geometry

This is a problem of complex analysis:

> Let $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. Show that if $|p(z)|\leq 1$ for arbitrary $z$ on the unit circle, then $p(z)=z^n$.

I convert this problem to a geometry problem: to prove that if for any point $P$ on unit circle and $n$ points $p_1,\cdots,p_n $ on the complex plane, we have the product
$$|P-p_1|\cdots |P-p_n|\leq 1$$
then we have $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_n=0$.

Comment: So, essentially the problem is asking you to prove that if $p:\{ e^{i\theta} \,|\, \theta\in\Bbb R\}\to\{c\in\Bbb C\,|\, |c|\le1\}$ then it must be true that $p:z\mapsto z^n$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint for a complex variables solution:

You have $$\int_0^{2\pi}|P(\exp(i\theta))|^2d\theta=2\pi\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|^2=2\pi+2\pi\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k|^2$$

Comment: To prove this equation seems to be difficult...

Comment: You have (with $a_n=1$) $$|P(\exp(i\theta))|^2=\sum a_k\overline{a_m}\exp(i(k-m)\theta)$$ and now you integrate; if $k\not =m$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(i(k-m)\theta)d\theta$ is zero.

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Proceed by induction on $n$.

For $n=1$, we have $f(z)=z$, so the base case is verified.

Next assume $n>1$, and assume the theorem holds for the case $\deg(f) = n-1$.

Suppose $a_0 \ne 0$.

Let $g(z)=z^nf(1/z)$, expanded. Then
$$g(z) = a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + \cdots + 1$$
By assumption, $a_0 \ne 0$, so $g$ is polynomial of degree $n$.

Then for $|z|=1$,
$$|g(z)| = |z^nf(1/z)| = |z^n||f(1/z)| = |f(1/z)| \le 1$$
Since $g$ is non-constant, the maximum modulus principle implies
$$|g(0)| < {\mathop{\max}_{|z|=1}} \{|g(z)|\}$$
contradiction, since from the expanded form of $g$, we have $g(0) = 1$.

It follows that $a_0=0$.

Then $f$ factors as $f(z) = zf_1(z)$ where $f_1(z)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n-1$.

But for $|z|=1,\,|f_1(z)| = |f(z)|,\;$hence$\;{\displaystyle{{\mathop{\max}_{|z|=1}}}}\{|f_1(z)|\}\le 1$.

Then by the inductive hypothesis, $f_1(z) = z^{n-1}$, hence $f(z) = z(z^{n-1}) = z^n$.

Thus, the induction is complete, and hence, so is the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a $p_i \neq 0$ and assume wlog that $p_1 \neq 0$. Then there is a point $P$ on the unit circle with $|P-p_1| > 1$. You can get this point geometrically by drawing the unit circle in the plane and putting $P$ opposite of $p_1$, or through calculation by putting
$$P = \frac{-p_1}{\Vert p_1 \Vert}.$$

Now the total product is still $\leq 1$, but the first factor is bigger than one, so we must have
$$|P-p_2| \cdot \ldots \cdot |P-p_n| \leq 1.$$

This allows us to use induction. The start for $n=1$ was just done, so we may assume from the last equation that $p_2 = p_3 = \ldots = p_n = 0$. But then the whole product is equal tot $|P-p_1|$, which is bigger than one by assumption.
Therefore, this assumption has to be false and we can conclude that $p_1 = 0$.

Comment: Induction does not work here. Because we have to choose the same point such that the product less than $1$.